# Create React App - Can't run npm run test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've had to eject my Create React App and now I can run my tests but the watch is completely broken.

If my tests fail or pass they do not carry on watching and I get the below error instead.

```
Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 test script 'node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom'.
```

I get this error when running `npm run test`

I've tried installing watchman to see if this made a difference with no success.

another thing that I've tried is adding the below line to my package.json file:

```
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js",
```

Comment: Did you read the doc ? It could be useful, especially the part about ejecting https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#srcsetuptestsjs

Comment: Thanks, I've actually already tried this.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like someone else might get this issue so I'm going to say how I fixed it.

It turns out that I need to run the below commands and your tests will be watching test files again.

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

I must of been out of sync or something.. Such a simple thing to do to fix a really annoying problem.